# Strange characters when transferring file with QTcpSocket

Tags: qt, qt4, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I'm trying to transfer a file using a QTcpSocket. The connection runs fine, but my problem is when I try to record the received bytes on a file. When I open the file there are some strange characters at the beginning of the file. What are these characters?

Comment: Analizing more I realized that the file always have 4 bytes more than the origin file. Independent if is a txt file or a binary file.

Comment: How do you read file, write it to socket, read from socket and write it back to the file? Without this parts of code we can't help you. If you would simply read file as QByteArray and write it as QByteArray there would be no encoding overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I was saving the whole object in my file. When we use the operator `>>` in a stream, the Qt serializes the whole object and sends it. If you want write only the bytes of your file, or whatever you want, you need to use `writeRawData` or the write methods passing the char * for the bytes.

:)

Answer (score 0):

They probably are describing the encoding of the file's text.  Such as UTF-8 v. ISO### standards.  If you take the block of text and set it to the proper encoding, those characters will most likely disappear.

Here is starting place to learn about it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toUtf8

Hope that helps.

Comment: Analizing more I realized that the file always have 4 bytes more than the origin file. Independent if is a txt file or a binary file

Comment: Is it an integer describing the size of the buffer?